# Is there a meta tag for website content rating?

Tags: metadata, content-management, rating

A client of mine said she noticed her site was blocked in a grocery store's wifi cafe. It contains nothing scandalous - it is just a travel blog. It said the reason for the restriction is Forbidden Category "Not Rated."

Is there some way to apply a rating to web content so that it won't be blocked? I've never come across this problem before.

Answer (score 7):

There's [this](http://www.webmarketingnow.com/tips/meta-tags-uncovered.html#rating) one.

```
<meta name="rating" content="value">
```

You can use on of the following values:

- general
- mature
- restricted
- 14 years
- safe for kids

Or possibly [PICS](http://www.w3.org/PICS/) rating which has now been superseded by [POWDER](http://www.w3.org/2007/powder/).

Comment: Google also accepts content="adult". See https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/safesearch

Answer (score -1):

The meta tag is practically useless.

There are services that spider sites and look for specific content and put them into categories so the client can block out the categories they wish to block out.

These services also have human 'raters' which put sites into categories because spiders aren't perfect.

In your client's case, the domain hasn't been spidered or human rated yet, and the grocery store wishes to block out anything that hasn't been checked out first by their service.

Comment: I highly doubt a grocery store has a website validation service in the back office.